# What's a good resource of book for Python programming in relation to quantitative finance?

Tags: programming, machine-learning

I know some of base Python, but I have only briefly used numpy, pandas, etc...

I was wondering what's a good resource to learn Python specifically for quantitative finance.  I know of plenty of books/resources to learn Python in general.  I was wondering if there was a resource for learning Python specifically when it came to quantitative research in finance.

I am trying to take a ML class in my school and need a quick crash course on Python that I can study over winter.  I'm hoping such a resource would include best practices (how the industry structures data) and specifically covers the most frequently used packages in quantitative finance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Hilpisch's books, especially *Python for Finance*. For derivatives pricing specifically, he wrote *Derivatives Analytics with Python*.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

I started with "Pandas for Data Analysis" by Wes Mckinney (the original developer of pandas) without ever using Python before.

After 3yrs I have the skills of a full stack developer, after some other projects using for example "Flask for Web Development" by Miguel Grinberg which is nice project for getting familiar with databases and SQLAlchemy class interaction.

There are some books specifically dedicated to Finance, but in my opinion it is perfectly valid to learn the generic programming principles and then apply them to the data analysis of choice whatever that may be.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the following books on Python and R
It includes times models, forecasting and predictive analysis models for stocks

1.Forecasting models – an overview with the help of R software : Time series - Past ,Present and Future

https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07VFY53B1

2.Python programming for Data Scientists: From Introductory concepts to Machine Learning Models